# ES6 Class is not a function when imported via System

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

how come Game is not a function  when imported via System

```
import Core from 'gameUnits/Core' 

export class Game { 
constructor() {
```

core:

```
export class Core {
    constructor(scene) {
    }
}
```

etc

and in the browser:

```
     <script src="bower_components/traceur/traceur.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('Game').then(function (Game) {
      game = new Game();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: `export default class Game {...}` might be more useful. Instead of a `Module` type object with a `Game` property, it exports `Game` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module object in your case isn't `Game`, it *contains* `Game`. Try:

```
System.import('Game').then(function ({Game}) {
  game = new Game();
});
```

Comment: What does {Game} actually mean?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper, it destructures the argument object, extracting the property `"Game"` and binding it to a variable of the same name. Same effect as naming the parameter `x` and binding `let Game = x.Game`.

Comment: is this a feature of es6?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper, yes.

Comment: chrome doesn't like is: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {**

Comment: @SuperUberDuper, because Chrome doesn't implement destructuring yet (neither modules, for that matter).

Comment: oh, I thought traceur took care of that

Comment: for some reason when I do **var sphere = new Core();** I see Core is undefined, even though I import it